# Unable to open terminal in remote desktop after rebooting aws ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, vnc-server, tightvnc

I have installed ***tightvncserver*** on my ubuntu ec2 server and I am able to get the remote desktop access but when I restart my server and connect to the ec2 remote desktop then I am not able to open the terminal.

I have installed the ***tightvncserver*** with help of this digitalocean's article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04

My xstartup looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are running this script via the **User Data** field on the Amazon EC2 instance.

User data scripts **only run on first boot**. They do *not* run on subsequent boots.

You can either:

- Install the server in some way that it automatically starts when the system starts, *or*
- Put a script in `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/` -- it will automatically run on *every* boot